# Save or build Jade as .php in Sublime Text?

Tags: php, sublimetext2, pug

I've just begun using Jade to write HTML. For now, I'd simply like to build the file with a .php extension. I'm fine just wring the PHP as-is for now.

Alternatively, how can I include jade-php in Sublime and build that?